# Can't Install ADT Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: plugins, adt

I am using the correct repository link. I tried to install the ADT plugin last time, and I accidentally stopped the installation when it gave me the security warning (I was supposed to click OK at that point). So now, I'm trying again, and I'm unable to install the Android Development Tools. It won't let me go on with the installation if I choose to install it.

Because I'm not allowed to post images, [here](http://s19.postimage.org/wwnct4spf/trouble.png) is a link to a picture explaining the problem. Notice the greyed out Next button, and the error at the bottom.

Now, either those tools aren't necessary for me to install, (which I doubt, but it could be possible), or I need to install them from somewhere else. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: I think the problems is in the scrollable area you are not showing under Details:, you have missing dependencies.

Comment: How would I install those dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Enable ***Contact all update sites during install to find software***

[image]

and be sure that you have Eclipse update site also enabled.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the repository and add it once again.

Comment: How do I remove a repository?

Comment: window -> preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Software Sites, select ADT and click remove.

Comment: I haven't installed the ADT plugin because of that!

Comment: I am talking about removing the ADT plugin site from list of sources. Not the ADT plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What you might be doing is using the eclipse you downloaded int the adt-bundle zip file. To fix this delete the eclipse folder, download a new installation of eclipse from eclipse's own site. Extract it to where the old one was and repeat what you've been trying.